# Real Time Progress Bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey I want to have a real time progress bar while loading a webpage on a website. The progress bar should show how much **actually a page has been loaded**. I searched a lot about this. I found various links which show how to do the same for an ASP.NET website. But I won't use it. Also there are ways which use just only images or javascript files to approximate the web page loaded like [this](http://yensdesign.com/2008/11/how-to-create-a-stylish-loading-bar-as-gmail-in-javascript/)

But is there any way by I can tell how much of my webpage is actually loaded and update the progress bar?
(the webpage will contain external files,stylesheets, javascript files and images)
Thanx in advance!

Comment: My browser has one of those already – so why duplicate that functionality?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at pace.js

> Include pace.js and the theme css of your choice on your page (as
>   early as is possible), and you're done!
>
> Pace will automatically monitor your ajax requests, event loop lag,
>   document ready state, and elements on your page to decide the
>   progress. On ajax navigation it will begin again!

http://github.hubspot.com/pace/